# autosave ajax, php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, prototypejs

I'm trying to make an autosave function with prototype and PHP but it doesn't work.

If I change *$('txtdoc').value* to *"any text"*, then *"any text"* is saved without any problems in the database

**JS**

```
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() { 
               intervalID = window.setInterval("autosave()",1000);
              });

              function autosave() {
                 new Ajax.Request('autosave.php?id=<?php echo $_GET["id"];?>', 
                { 
                method: 'post',
                  parameters: {txtdoc: $('txtdoc').value},

                                });
                            }
```

**autosave.php**

```
<?php 
include '../../db.php'; 

if(isset($_POST["txtdoc"])){
$did = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["id"]);
$txtdoc = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["txtdoc"]);
$sql="UPDATE doc SET txt = '$txtdoc' WHERE id = '$did'";
mysql_query($sql); 
}

?>
```

**Form**

```
<form action="" method="post">
<textarea id="txtdoc" name="txtdoc" style="width:605px; height:200px;"><?php echo $txt; ?></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Save"/>
</form>

<script>
autosave();
</script>
```

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by "doesn't work".

Comment: Is the JS in a .php file (ie. is it being interpreted by a PHP interpreter)? Otherwise the line `new Ajax.Request('autosave.php?id=<?php echo $_GET["id"];?>',` will not give the correct result..

Comment: Yes, the JS is in a .php file

Comment: can you identify what's actually working and not working. Is your AJAX call actually firing or not? - you will be able to see in Firebug if it is

Comment: Text that I write between <textarea> </ textarea> directly in the code saved without any problems in the database. However, when I write text in the textarea with a web browser then nothing is saved.

Comment: Try to install Firebug in order to check if the AJAX request is done repeately and if the POST values are actually empty. Maybe $('txtdoc').getValue() instead of .value ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using prototype, then (unless you have a reason why it doesn't work) you are probably best off using it...

Create a hidden div:

```
<div id="dummy" style="display: none"></div>
```

Then try this:

```
document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
  new Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater(
    'dummy',
    'autosave.php?id=<?php echo $_GET["id"];?>', {
      method: 'post',
      parameters: {
        txtdoc: $F('txtdoc')
      }
    }
  , 10)
});
```

What this does is use the PeriodicalUpdater (triggering every 10 seconds) to call your PHP script. The parameter is read using $F (The unified field reader method).

Additionally, I notice you had a trailing comma after the parameters: object. This will fail on IE as it doesn't allow trailing commas.